My PC don't detect my camera
I have a USB camera connected to my computer but isn't detected, and I can't see it in device manager.
I tried to restart the computer, connect the webcam to different USB ports, camera troubleshooting...

Does it play a sound of connecting/disconnecting when you plug it in? If not, then it's not reading the USB at all. Try to replace the USB cable or check in Device Manager if anything comes up with a Yellow flag or an unusual sign. If so, try to update the driver via Windows Update.

it may also prove useful to test the USB camera to a different pc and/or a different OS (BTW: from my experience I can say that sometimes Linux was able to connect to devices that windows totally ignored even when using the vendor's drivers)

In Device Manager nothing comes up, but I tried in other computers and it works perfectly, I installed the drivers manually.

I just installed the drivers manually and it works now.
